# How do I disable Firefox gestures?

Tags: firefox

I hate Firefox gestures, I just want to click, but if my move shake during click it happens a mess!

How do I disable firefox gestures?

Answer (score 18):

You need to change the configuration, which you can do by typing `about:config` in the address bar and press the "Enter", just like you type the url of a website to open a website. If you see a warning just confirm.

Filter the available settings to the gesture-related settings by typing `browser.gesture` in the search bar at the top of the page.
Doubleclick on the relevant settings, and delete their contents if you want to disable them.

Close the `about:config`-tab once you're done.

Comment: I obtained this:
[![gestures.png](https://s2.postimg.org/lzbsc77bd/gestures.png)](https://postimg.org/image/n1lyuqq4l/)

What are the correct values to insert?

Comment: According to this (and what worked for me) is to just put empty values for all the "string" entries: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1003526